# How to preprocess or include a coffee script in a coffee script?

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

I'm taking over my co-worker's coffee script project. He coded all the classes in one single coffee script file.

I like to separate all the classes into their own files. I found out that I can separate files then export the class to 'window' object. The problem with that method is that coffee script generates separate javascript files.

Is there a way to separate coffee script files then compile them into one single js file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Coffescript compiler has a `--join` command exactly for this case.
You can do it like this:

```
coffee --join project.js --compile myCoffeeFolder/*.coffee
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to compile your coffeescript files into separate js files to quickly check whether the generated js code matches your expectations. In that case you could use [uglifyjs](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS) in a second step to compile them into one file and even minify it (for faster loading etc.).